# Tell the order of fields submitted from a form

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have a form that will allow users to move around the inputs (using jQuery) into any order they want.  For the form below, a user might want "fieldD" followed by "fieldA", "fieldB", "fieldC".

Example form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">  
  <input type="submit">
  <table>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldA"></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldB"></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldC"></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldD"></td></tr> 
  </table>  
</form>
```

What is the best way to capture the ordering the user chose when they submitted the form?

Comment: Did any of these answers help?

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: @iambriansreed Classic ASP is the server side language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking ideas from the answers, I ended up using jQuery to traverse my table to determine the ordering.  When I actually implement it, I will determine the ordering (by traversing my table) at the time the form is submitted.

Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/kq8tT/6/

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have done the following:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">  
  <input type="submit">
  <table>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldA"></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldB"></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldC"></td></tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" name="fieldD"></td></tr> 
  </table>  
  <input type="hidden" name="fields" value="fieldA,fieldB,fieldC,fieldD" />
</form>
```

Namely, added a hidden field with field names in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

You could store those input-values in an array and number the field-names:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">  
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="text" name="field[1]" />
    <input type="text" name="field[2]" />
    <input type="text" name="field[3]" />
    <input type="text" name="field[4]" />
</form>
```

The field names need to get rewritten after every complete sorting action.

```
// this will result in a PHP-array, e.g.
$_POST['field'][0]

foreach( $_POST['field'] as $indexAsSetViaJs => $fieldValue ) {
    // process values in desired order
}
```

Comment: @Sebi2020 The concept holds true for other server-side languages as well…

Answer (score -2):

By the specifications, the order of the fields in form data is undefined. In practice, it tends to be the textual order, but especially if the order is changed client-side, I would not count on it.

The best approach is probably to create an array of field names and to modify it whenever the order is changed. If it makes sense to use the page without client-side scripting, then it would be safest to include a hidden field, containing the fields in their textual order, and dynamically replacing its content by data from the array when the form data is being submitted.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is factually incorrect. The HTML specification states that the order of key/value pairs in a POST request body must be in the same order as the fields appear in the HTML document. See this answer which gives a citation for HTML4.01: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3712617/159145  - while HTML5's spec (as of December 2019) states the values must be in "tree order" which is a stricter version of HTML4.01's definition ( https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constructing-form-data-set )