# Parse form inputs that belong together in Go

Tags: html, forms, go

I wonder how to parse form input fields that belong together in Go.

The following example has 2 inputs for each number and text.
Both names of the inputs and the numbers are identical.
**The inputs of each `<li>` belong together, and they need to be parsed like that.**

Is there anything that ensures correct order when parsing the inputs...? 
Or is is it better to combine each name of the input with an index e.g. 
mynumber1 and mytext1, mynumber2 and mytext2?

```
<form>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="number" name="mynumber" value="">
            <input type="text" name="mytext" value="">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="number" name="mynumber" value="">
            <input type="text" name="mytext" value="">
        </li>
        </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that they'll be submitted together. If they're distinct inputs they should have distinct names, and if they're related they should have related names, e.g. `mynumber1` and `mytext1`.

Comment: @Adrian, there is actually a predefined order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712481/what-is-the-expected-order-of-an-array-submitted-in-an-html-form/3712617#3712617

Comment: @BurakSerdar yet Go makes no such guarantee of the order of elements in `Request.Form`/`Request.PostForm` or `URL.Query`.

Comment: ParseQuery simply appends values found to the slice in a map, so there is no guarantee on whether `mynumber` or `text` will come first, but consecutive values of `mynumber` and `text` will be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in  Burak Serdar's comments to the question, the values for a given field name are in document order.  If the document contains pairs of [successful](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)  "mynumber" and "mytext" inputs, then use the same index in both slices to get the corresponding values:

```
 // Set req.Form by calling ParseForm.
 if err := req.ParseForm(); err != nil {
    // handle bad form error
 }
 texts := req.Form["mytext"]
 numbers := req.Form["mynumber"]

 ...

 if i >= len(texts) || i >= len(numbers) {
     // handle index out or range error
 }
 text := texts[i]
 number := nubmers[i]
```

See also the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set).